# Flex 4.5.1 runtime ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable ... is not defined

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

Ok, I need some help on this one.  I upgraded from Flash Builder 4 to Flash Builder 4.5 and have switched my project to the 4.5.1 sdk.  I use an ant script to build my project, so I modified it to use the appropriate flexTasks.jar, mxmlc, etc...

Now, if I start out with a blank bin-debug folder, then build and run the app everything works fine.  However, if I then make a code change and build (without deleting the bin-debug) then run the app I get a runtime error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable ... is not defined.
at flash.display::MovieClip/nextFrame()
at mx.managers::SystemManager/deferredNextFrame()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:284]
at mx.managers::SystemManager/preloader_preloaderDocFrameReadyHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2633]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:515]
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Again, if I delete the bin-debug folder and compile again it runs with no problems.

The variable it complains about is always a Class variable that points to an image file used as an icon.  The code I use to create the var:

```
[Embed(source="/assets/icons/close-32x32.png")] 
public var closeIcon:Class;
```

The file exists, and I verified that when it gives that error the file is in the bin-debug/assets/icons folder and the src/assets/icons/ folder.

After the error is thrown, if I hit the continue button in Flash Builder it then throws the same error again on the next Class variable pointing to an image file.

Any ideas?  The delete/recompile takes several minutes, so obviously this is driving me mad.

**Edit: Ant task that compiles in debug mode:**

```
<target name="compile-debug">
    <echo>Compile MXML</echo>
    <mxmlc 
        file="${SRC_DIR}/${MAIN_SOURCE_FILE}"               
        debug="true"
        optimize="false"
        output="${DEBUG_DIR}/${APP_ROOT_FILE}" 
        append="true"               
        actionscript-file-encoding="UTF-8"              
        keep-generated-actionscript="false"
        link-report="MyReport.xml"
        maxmemory="2048m"
        incremental="true">

        <!-- Get default compiler options. -->
        <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
        <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/air-config.xml"/>

        <!-- List of path elements that form the roots of ActionScript class hierarchies. -->
        <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>

        <!-- Include Themes -->
        <!-- NOTE: Spark theme required -->
        <theme dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/themes/Spark/">
        <include name="spark.css" />
        </theme>
        <theme dir="${FLEX_HOME}/samples/themes/spark_graphite/">
        <include name="spark_graphite.css" />
        </theme>                

        <!-- List of SWC files or directories that contain SWC files. -->
        <compiler.library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks" append="true">
        <include name="libs" />
        <include name="../bundles/{locale}" />                  
        </compiler.library-path>

        <!-- uncomment if you have external libs (swc files) -->    
        <library-path dir="${LIB_DIR}/riaspace/" append="true">
        <include name="*.swc" />
        </library-path> 
        <library-path dir="${LIB_DIR}/AlivePDF/" append="true">
        <include name="*.swc" />
        </library-path>             
        <library-path dir="${LIB_DIR}/coltware/" append="true">
        <include name="*.swc" />
        </library-path>
    </mxmlc>

</target>
```

Where FLEX_HOME = *< path to flash builder >/sdks/4.5.1*

Comment: I'd guess there is something w/ the ANT Script you're using, but am not really sure what that could be.

Comment: Embed directive is buggy and compiler-time-wasting, try this approach - http://kachurovskiy.com/2010/storing-icons-in-external-zip-and-seamless-work-with-composite-icons/

Comment: @www.Flextras.com - Thanks for the reply. I've edited my question to include my ant build task

Comment: @Maxim Kachurovskiy - Very interesting approach that I'll have to explore a bit.  Was hoping I could get the build to work with embeds as it should though.

Comment: Are you using a custom preloader?

Comment: @J_A_X, No custom preloader.  I should mention this app is an air app (though probably obvious from the ant build script)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is buried in the middle of [Maxim's post](http://kachurovskiy.com/2010/storing-icons-in-external-zip-and-seamless-work-with-composite-icons/) that he referenced in a comment above:

--> Try turning off incremental compilation.

I had the same issue here with a simple `mimeType='application/octet-stream'` embed, and when reading Maxim's text this jumped out because I'd recently changed my custom build tools to use inremental compilation: "Embed sometimes fails during incremental compilation"

The result of this failure is that the .swf contains something like this:

```
<DefineBinaryData id='1' length='1024' />
```

which looks like it's empty, instead of this (from the working file):

```
<DefineBitsLossless2 id='1' encoding='base64'>
(.. in my case, 1024 bytes of base64-encoded data)
</DefineBitsLossless2>
```

(This solved it for me, so a big thank-you to Maxim. I hope it solves it for you too.)

Comment: could you tell us how you enabled disabled incremental compilation?

Comment: @feresr That's so long ago I've got no memory of it, sorry. I suspect I must have just used this though: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ed3.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I "Clean"ed the project and then re ran. It worked.

Comment: Did it for me! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have Flash Builder 4.7 and am using sdk 4.5.1A.

I was using Flash Player debugger version 15 before Christmas of 2014 and everything was working.  I had Firefox set up as the default browser.  However, in 2015, Adobe has a new player so I upgraded to version 16 and that's when I got the same problem.  After much struggle, I found that the problem had to do with the new version of Firefox Flash player debugger.  I had to switch the default browser to Internet Explorer and installed the Internet Explorer Flash player debugger.  Prior to debugging, I had to clean and update first.  Then everything worked again!