# Why does mxmlc Incremental Compile cause a fault relating to particular embedded asset?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, mxmlc

I have a swf which embeds around 40 various png and fxg objects using the embed metatag... eg.:

```
public class OneOfMyEbeddedAssets
{
    [Embed(source = "./assets/OneOfMyEbeddedAssets.png")]
    private static const shapeClass: Class; 

    public static function get bitmapData():BitmapData
    {
        var bm:Bitmap = new shapeClass();
        return bm.bitmapData;
    }
}
```

When it compiles with the incremental tag, I notice a number of classes and fxgs are recompiled each time, saying "Reason: one of the assets has been updated", or "Reason: It's dependent file, .as has been updated". The build completes successfully.

Then, when I run my application, I get a message in the flash log:

> [Fault] exception, information=ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable
>   OneOfMyEbeddedAssets_shapeClass is not defined.

When I explore the swf file, and look at the Symbols embedded in it, I can see the required shape class has actually been embedded properly. The message is not for every embedded asset, just one in particular; and not necessarily the first one accessed in the code.

**The problem disappears if I don't do an incremental compile... any ideas why?**

Comment: My only suggestion is to file a bug: http://bugs.adobe.com/flex/

Comment: Did you manage to file a bug? I wont to upvote it if you did...

Comment: Just faced this problem in my project... awful bug :(

Comment: Yep - i logged https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASC-4351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASC-4351).

I found the exact reproduction steps so hopefully this bug can get upvoted and fixed.

Comment: Legend! I found it difficult to reproduce with a lightweight compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this a known bug with embedding assets and incremental compile not working correctly.

See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150490/flex-4-5-1-runtime-referenceerror-error-1065-variable-is-not-defined)